# LINQ to add continuous records based on a flag to JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq, .net-core

I have an Entity with set of records

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExitTime { get; set; }
    public bool CheckFlag { get; set; }
}   

var employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 1, 0, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 2, 15, 0), CheckFlag = true });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 4, 50, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 5, 15, 0), CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 35, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 45, 0), CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 20, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 30, 0), CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 30, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 4, 45, 0), CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 2, 30, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 15, 0), CheckFlag = true });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 1, 45, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 2, 15, 0), CheckFlag = false });
```

I want the json group by `Employee` and sorted by `EntryTime` and add the records based on `CheckFlag`. If `CheckFlag` is true, then it will be a single result and if `CheckFlag` is false, then iterate till next `CheckFlag` is true.

> I have solved this using foreach loop, but I am wondering whether I can achieve this using `LINQ`

What is Expected

```
[
    {
        "EmpID": 1,
        "TrackTimes": [
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T01:00:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T02:15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EmpID": 1,
        "TrackTimes": [
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T03:20:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T03:30:00"
            },
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T03:35:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T03:45:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EmpID": 2,
        "TrackTimes": [
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T01:45:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T02:15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EmpID": 2,
        "TrackTimes": [
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T02:30:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T03:15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "EmpID": 2,
        "TrackTimes": [
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T03:30:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T04:45:00"
            },
            {
                "StartTime": "2020-02-16T04:50:00",
                "EndTime": "2020-02-16T05:15:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I tried (foreach group by and order by)

```
public class TrackRecord
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public List<TrackTime> TrackTimes { get; set; }
}

public class TrackTime
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}

var trackRecord = new List<TrackRecord>();
var trackTimes = new List<TrackTime>();
bool checkflag = true;
int prevEmpId = 0;
foreach (var result in employees.GroupBy(x => x.EmpID))
{
    if (!checkflag && trackTimes.Count > 0)
    {
        trackRecord.Add(new TrackRecord()
        {
            EmpID = prevEmpId,
            TrackTimes = trackTimes
        });
        checkflag = true;
        trackTimes = new List<TrackTime>();
    }

    foreach (var employee in result.OrderBy(x => x.EntryTime))
    {
        if (employee.CheckFlag)
        {
            if (!checkflag && trackTimes.Count > 0)
            {
                trackRecord.Add(new TrackRecord()
                {
                    EmpID = employee.EmpID,
                    TrackTimes = trackTimes
                });
                checkflag = true;
                trackTimes = new List<TrackTime>();
            }

            trackRecord.Add(new TrackRecord()
            {
                EmpID = employee.EmpID,
                TrackTimes = new List<TrackTime>() { new TrackTime() { StartTime = employee.EntryTime, EndTime = employee.ExitTime } }
            });                        
        }
        else
        {
            trackTimes.Add(new TrackTime() { StartTime = employee.EntryTime, EndTime = employee.ExitTime });
            checkflag = false;
        }
    }

    prevEmpId = result.Key;
}

if (!checkflag && trackTimes.Count > 0)
{
    trackRecord.Add(new TrackRecord()
    {
        EmpID = prevEmpId,
        TrackTimes = trackTimes
    });
    checkflag = true;
    trackTimes = new List<TrackTime>();
}

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackRecord));
```

Comment: If you group by `CheckFlag`, there will be a two groups with `true` or `false`. You have two items with `CheckFlag` equals `true`. How did you get a single result?

Comment: Please, share your `foreach` loop code and how did you get an expected result

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, added foreach code.

Comment: You are grouping items by `EmpID`, not the `CheckFlag` property

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla, can you add the expected output when there are two different `EmpId`s, e.g. with values 1 and 2?

Comment: Why does it matter if it is solved with a for loop or LINQ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it really doesnt matter. I am just curious what LINQ can do

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla, I think you should also mix the `EntryTime` hours between `EmpId`s so that your example would cover more use cases (currently, your example just `new`s all `EmpId` by `EntryTime` order).

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla, not really, you just changed the insertion order, instead of `EntryTime` order. What I meant is e.g. `{ EmpID = 2, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 1, 0, 0) ... }, { EmpID = 1, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 1, 30, 0) ... }, { EmpID = 2, EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 2, 30, 0) ... }` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, let's move `Employee`'s `DateTime` properties into your-already-defined `TrackTime` class, as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public TrackTime TrackTime { get; set; }
    public bool CheckFlag { get; set; }
}
```

Then your Linq would be:

```
var records = employees
  .GroupBy(e => new { e.EmpID, e.CheckFlag })
  .SelectMany(g =>
     g.Key.CheckFlag ?
     g.Select(e => new List<Employee> { e }).ToList() :
     new List<List<Employee>> { g.ToList() })
  .Select(es => new TrackRecord
  {
      EmpID = es.First().EmpID,
      TrackTimes = es.Select(e => e.TrackTime).ToList()
  })
  .OrderBy(e => e.EmpID)
  .ThenBy(e => e.TrackTimes.First().EntryTime)
  .ToList();
```

And with the following input:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 1, 0, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 2, 15, 0) }, CheckFlag = true });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 15, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 30, 0) }, CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 30, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 45, 0) }, CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 45, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 4, 15, 0) }, CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 1, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 4, 30, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 5, 15, 0) }, CheckFlag = true });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 1, 0, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 2, 15, 0) }, CheckFlag = true });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 15, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 30, 0) }, CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 30, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 45, 0) }, CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 3, 45, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 4, 15, 0) }, CheckFlag = false });
employees.Add(new Employee() { EmpID = 2, TrackTime = new TrackTime { EntryTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 4, 30, 0), ExitTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 16, 5, 15, 0) }, CheckFlag = true });
```

You'd get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "EmpID  ": 1,
    "TrackTimes  ": [
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T01:00:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T02:15:00  "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmpID  ": 1,
    "TrackTimes  ": [
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:15:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:30:00  "
      },
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:30:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:45:00  "
      },
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:45:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T04:15:00  "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmpID  ": 1,
    "TrackTimes  ": [
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T04:30:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T05:15:00  "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmpID  ": 2,
    "TrackTimes  ": [
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T01:00:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T02:15:00  "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmpID  ": 2,
    "TrackTimes  ": [
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:15:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:30:00  "
      },
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:30:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:45:00  "
      },
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T03:45:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T04:15:00  "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "EmpID  ": 2,
    "TrackTimes  ": [
      {
        "EntryTime  ": "2020-02-16T04:30:00  ",
        "ExitTime  ": "2020-02-16T05:15:00  "
      }
    ]
  }
]
```